# Asking for a raise without sounding like I am threatening to leave? Is this even possible?

Tags: salary, raise, germany

Facts:

- I worked for a company for 1 year and then joined my recent company
- I really enjoy working here
- I have 10+ years in sw development
- I really think (honestly) that I am an employee that anyone would like to have due to my enthusiasm and work quality
- I am a foreigner who has lived in Germany for 2 years.
- I speak German fluently
- my company is doing really well financially.

Situation:
People brought to my attention that students job posting were offering a similar hour based salary than mine (from 4 euro less up to the same value.) I dismissed that for a while. Now many people on my team decided to quit (for different reason) and on this context of leaving, farewell parties and so on I got the information that people with no prior experience were receiving just a little bit less than I do and some people with same age and a little bit more experience were getting twice my salary.

I got very frustrated because I have lots of responsibilities and I do my job well and I was repeatedly told so by my boss. I scheduled a meeting to talk about it because it just extinguished my motivation and I have the feeling that they used my lack of knowledge of the job market to give me a low salary.

I will ask for a big raise, so I am nearer to the ones my work is similar to.
The thing is: many people of my team are leaving, in two months my team will be reduced to 2 people (me +1, and I am older in the company). I do not want to use this as a pressure tool. But I will look for alternatives if we do not get to some number that I am happy with.
**How do I tell them that, without sounding as a threat and being known as someone who used their delicate situation for my benefit?**

This is not a duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid) because I am focused on an unusual situation (my team members left and I am one of the few remaining) and I want to avoid my request sounding like a threat.

Comment: So, what *are* you going to do if you don't get a raise?

Comment: @philip I will look for alternatives and leave. But I would rather stay because I enjoy working here

Comment: @gnat see edit. This is not a duplicate

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your point @paparazzi

Comment: The thing is: I know how I want to go about the fact that I am underpaid. My question is: how do I do so I do not come over as "I noticed that you are in a delicate situation and will profit from it"

Comment: But your "request" is a threat. Doesn't really matter how you sugar coat it.

Comment: I will look other companies. @joe

Comment: I think this a duplicate of my question "How to give a polite ultimatum?"

Comment: @joe yes, I think this is going to be the way. I was just thinking that somehow I would not sound very harsh, but maybe, like Philip days, this is just the way I am doing it, so there is no way to (nor reason) to pretend it is not. Thanks for your help

Comment: Either there is no threat, or you have no bargaining chip. There is no other way. Sorry. Incentive is everything. I'd write a fuller answer if I could.

Comment: I assume when you say you don't want it to sound like a threat, what you mean is you want to know how to make it a polite threat.  Otherwise, what's the point?  Why would they give you a raise if there are no consequences for them in not doing so?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this even possible?

No, there is no real way to do that.

I think that in your scenario you would be better off finding another job, and at that point have your salary discussion with another offer in hand.  This also serves as terrific **enforcement of the salary your requesting**.

This approach will also validate your worth in the market.  This approach may take longer, but if you do not get the salary increase you're looking for, you will end up down this path anyway.

Your request for a salary increase will imply to your employer that you are unhappy and may look elsewhere if your wish is not granted.

Comment: That is the point sir.  There is no real way to so that.

Comment: I will when I'm back in front of a keyboard

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Question adjusted.